# Partitioning Not working fine in Google BigQuery when SQL Query contains a sub-query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partitioning

I have the following table structure in the Big-query

```
**query_all_partition**
property_unique_date    DATE    REQUIRED    
page_url    STRING  REQUIRED    
click   INTEGER REQUIRED    
impression  INTEGER REQUIRED    
position    FLOAT   REQUIRED
```

Here, I have specified partitioning over property_unique_date

```
**property_data**

fetch_date  DATE    REQUIRED    
property_url    STRING  REQUIRED    
property_unique_date    DATE    REQUIRED
```

## Let me give you a brief background

I wanted to capture google search analytics data for different websites (like the clicks, impressions happening for a particular website or redirection to those websites based on some keywords etc)

Earlier I was having a single table with following fields and partitioning was on fetch_date

- fetch_date
- property_url
- page_url
- click
- impression
- position

So, when I was querying based on fetch_dates i..e between two dates, query processing was happening only on the required data and this was accounting to reduce in cost. However, this approach was fine if we are storing only data for one website or property url. When I started storing data for different property, even querying for one of the property and for particular fetch date range, it was processing data for all the properties within the specified date range resulting in large data processing and costing, because partitioning cannot be done on fields other than date/timestamp.

So, I came up with the approach where I created two tables

- query_all_partition
- property_data

So, I started storing a date for a combination of property_url and fetch_date. Like I gave the range 1971-01-01 to 1980-12-31 for storing data for say property P1. So,say I am storing data for each data for P1 from 2018 Jan, it will be

```
fetch_date  property_url   property_unique_date
2018-01-01   P1               1971-01-01
2018-01-02   P1               1971-01-02
2018-01-01   P2               1981-01-01
2018-01-02   P2               1981-01-02
```

With this approach, I can store atleast 10 years of data for each property. Under query_partition_all, I started storing property_unique_date instead of fetch_date and property_url

Now, for testing I have stored 1 month of data for two properties. P1 being very large property and P2 being a very small property. Storing july 2018 data for both the property with property unique date assigned for P1 from 1971-01-01 to 1971-01-31 as July is 31 days and for P2 from 1981-01-01 to 1981-01-31.

Ran the below queries and attaching the snapshots for the same

Two property are
- P1 (large property)  (1971-01-01 to 1971-01-31)
- P2 (small property) (1981-01-01 to 1981-01-31)

I ran the below queries

```
select page_url, sum(click) as click,sum(impression) as impression from `searchanalytics.query_all_partition` where property_unique_date BETWEEN ('1971-01-01') and ('1971-01-31') group by page_url
```

[Image with property_unique_dates hardcoded for property P1. Please see the data being processed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5jWG.png)

```
select page_url, sum(click) as click,sum(impression) as impression from `searchanalytics.query_all_partition` where property_unique_date BETWEEN ('1981-01-01') and ('1981-01-31') group by page_url
```

[Image with property_unique_dates hardcoded for property P2. Please see the data being processed.Its small so till here everything is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bisl8.png)

Issue comes, when instead of hard-coding property unique dates, I start fetching it from subquery(query from propertydata table). Please see the query and data processed as part of the 3rd and 4th images. below are the queries. Data processed is the complete data

```
select page_url, sum(click) as click,sum(impression) as impression from `searchanalytics.query_all_partition` where property_unique_date BETWEEN (select property_unique_date from `searchanalytics.property_data` where fetch_date='2018-01-01' and property_url='P1') and (select property_unique_date from `searchanalytics.property_data` where fetch_date='2018-01-31' and property_url='P1') group by page_url

select page_url, sum(click) as click,sum(impression) as impression from `searchanalytics.query_all_partition` where property_unique_date BETWEEN (select property_unique_date from `searchanalytics.property_data` where fetch_date='2018-01-01' and property_url='P2') and (select property_unique_date from `searchanalytics.property_data` where fetch_date='2018-01-31' and property_url='P2') group by page_url
```

[Data for property P1 with property unique dates not hardcoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4bM8.png)

[Data for property P2 with property unique dates not hardcoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTh2G.png)

In both 3rd and 4th, its processing the complete data of the table and not the subset. Why is this so. Can anybody explain and how to resolve this?

Would appreciate your detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pruning_limiting_partitions):

> Complex queries that require the evaluation of multiple stages of a query in order to resolve the predicate (such as inner queries or subqueries) will not prune partitions from the query.

So no, you cannot use a filter based a subquery and expect that it will restrict the scan just to the matched partitions.